# Cant serialize when using enum as key in Hashmap

Tags: serialization, rust, serde

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Demo {
    #[serde(with = "serde_with::json::nested")]
    pub something: HashMap<Option<Resource>, bool>,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize, Eq, Hash)]
pub enum Resource {
    #[serde(rename = "cpu")]
    Cpu,
    #[serde(rename = "memory")]
    Memory,
}
```

I am using an Enum property "Resource" as my hashmap key.
Now, I want to send my data to an HTTP endpoint, so I want to serialize the data.
This is how I did it :

```
let mut something = HashMap::new();
something.insert(Some(Cpu), true);

let data = Demo{
    something: something,
};


let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&data).unwrap();
println!("serialized {}", serialized);
```

But, the to_string is failing saying ==> `Error("key must be a string", line: 0, column: 0)`

can I map my enum values to be string at the time of serialization ? How to solve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the issue is that the keys of the `Hashmap` are `Option<Resource>`, not `Resource`, which are not serialized as a string? You could try adding a `None` variant to your `Resource` `enum` to avoid having to wrap it in an `Option`.

Comment: @BlackBeans This is only a portion of the real programme, It is important to keep the key as type Enum. I am just looking for a trait, which can help me convert enum to string during serialization

Comment: @KevalBhogayata I think you're misunderstanding. Using your enum as a key is probably fine, but using `Option` as a key is not -- what should the serialized key be for the `None` key? `null` is not a valid key in JSON.

Comment: Yes, removing the Option part worked for me. Thanks, @BlackBeans

Comment: @KevalBhogayata Out of curiosity, what did you expect `Demo { something: [(None, false)].into_iter().collect() }` to serialize to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different annotations from `serde_with` to make your example work. The problem how you used `serde_with::json::nested` is that it converts the whole `HashMap` into a `String`, which fails, because the keys do not serialize as strings. If you apply the attribute only to the key part, it works.

```rust
#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Demo {
    #[serde_as(as = "HashMap<serde_with::json::JsonString, _>")]
    pub something: HashMap<Option<Resource>, bool>,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Huh, I wrote a whole crate for this: [serde_json_any_key](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json_any_key). Now I'm wondering if this was really necessary. Maybe the existing serde_with::json::JsonString annotation was sufficient. Mine might be slightly more flexible in that it supports serializing Vec<(K,V)> as if it were a map<K,V>, and that it can serialize standalone data structures without needing an annotation. IDK.